# Kubernetes services cannot reach each other anymore

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I’m running Kubernetes on GKE, this was working before but about 2 days ago something changed. I don’t think I changed anything to my configuration. My services do not seem to work anymore. None of my services can talk to each other. When SSHing into a running pod I cannot ping them via their service name but also not via their internal IP addresses. The external IP of the load balancer is not approachable. Here is an example of how I define the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    ksonnet.io/component: app-name
  name: app-name
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-name
```

And here the service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    ksonnet.io/component: app-name
  name: app-name
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: x.x.x.x
  ports:
  - port: 4999
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: app-name
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I am fairly new to Kubernetes and networking and I have no clue where to look or how to debug this issue.

EDIT:

Here are the relevant `kubectl get services -n test`

```
dashboard       ClusterIP      10.47.242.176   <none>        5000/TCP         1h
app-name        LoadBalancer   10.47.246.63    x.xxx.xx.xx   4999:31439/TCP   1h
```

Then here is the `kubectl describe service app-name -n test`

```
Name:                     app-name
Namespace:                test
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/deploy-manager=ksonnet
                          ksonnet.io/component=app-name
Annotations:              ksonnet.io/managed: {pristine...}
Selector:                 app=app-name
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.47.246.63
IP:                       xx.xxx.xx.x
LoadBalancer Ingress:     xx.xxx.xx.x
Port:                     <unset>  4999/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31439/TCP
Endpoints:                10.44.1.141:5000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

EDIT 2: I tried the curl command on the default port and it timed out:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to app-name port 80: Connection timed out
```

When trying it on the full endpoint it got a connection refused:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to app-name port 4999: Connection refused
```

When looking at the deployment I get the following pod template:

```
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=app-name
  Containers:
   model-manager:
    Image:      gcr.io/ns-delay/app-name:0.1
    Port:       5000/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
```

Comment: can you share `kubectl get services` and `kubectl describe service your-service`

Comment: Yeah I will do that directly, thanks

Comment: This is only one example but none of the services can talk to each other anymore

Comment: Can you execute `kubectl exec -it app-name-pod-id -n test -- bash -c 'curl http://dashboard'` and paste the ourput

Comment: I don't know what's that CLusterIP is on port 5000, but it's irrelevant. What's the containerPort of  your Deployment? Your service sends traffic to your pods, not to another service.

Comment: @edbighead I posted the response to the basic URI and to the one that I know is listening

Comment: @suren I posted the relevant pod template

Comment: according to your curl exit code, it managed to resolve IP address for dashboard app. This means you have errors within your deployment/service ports definition. can you paste your deployment.yaml

Comment: Please run ```kubectl get endpoints``` to check if your services are correctly tied to your endpoints, Please check the selectors on your Services vs Deployment yaml, they should match to get the Endpoint binding correctly

Comment: As i see your selector in service is not matching the labels in Deployment , change to   ```metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-name``` in your Deployment and it should work then.

Comment: @JanvanderVegt did you try restarting the kube-dns service. see what happens, does the endpoints get reloaded?

Comment: I'll try that @san

Comment: It looks to be related with this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119820482 the versions match up perfectly

Comment: I started a new cluster with older versions and it is still not working...

Answer (score 0):

As i see your selector in service is not matching the labels in Deployment , change to

`metadata:
  labels:
    app: app-name`

in your Deployment and it should work then.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to change anything, the metadata is in the specs of the containers of the deployment

Comment: The metadata in the specs of the containers of deployments is ```ksonnet.io/component: app-name``` whereas when the service is being created , it is looking to match a Deployment having a selector ```app: app-name``` , Clearly those two are not same and that is why you are seeing the binding not done. You might also run ```Kubectl get endpoints``` to see if the endpoint for this service is actually created ( which probably not has been since you are facing this issue) . Please look into [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) link for details